# How to use @media to rectify responsive display?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I  trying to resolve a compatibility layout issue with portrait and landscape in mobile. I have a group of divs that display correctly in a mobile landscape, but not a mobile portrait. Using @media doesn't seem to have solved the issue, but `orientation: portrait` doesn't work either. Please see [this page](https://adsler.co.uk/browse-adsler/) on your mobile phone and find CSS HTML below.  For example of how it should look, please see https://www.gumtree.com on mobile.

```css
.awpcp-listings {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.awpcp-listing-excerpt {
  min-width: 20%;
  margin-right: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px #888888 !important;
  border-style: solid;
  color: grey;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.awpcp-listing-excerpt-inner {
  min-width: 140px;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.awpcp-listing-excerpt-content {
  display: none;
}

.awpcp-listing-title {
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.awpcp-listing-excerpt-extra {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt $awpcpdisplayaditems 
    $isfeaturedclass" data-breakpoints-class-prefix="awpcp- 
    listing-excerpt" data-breakpoints='{"tiny": [0,328], "small": 
    [328,600], "medium": [600,999999]}'>
  <div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-thumbnail">
    $awpcp_image_name_srccode
  </div>
  <div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-inner" style="w">
    <h4 class="awpcp-listing-title">$title_link</h4>
    <div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt- 
    content">$excerpt</div>
  </div>
  <div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-extra">
    $awpcpadpostdate $awpcp_city_display $awpcp_state_display $awpcp_display_adviews $awpcp_display_price $awpcpextrafields
```

Answer (score 0):

please update css classes, i hope that can resolve your problem

```
.awpcp-listings {
    display: flex;
}
.awpcp-listing-excerpt {
    min-width: 10%;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px #888888 !important;
    border-style: solid;
    color: grey;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work. Puts all the divs out of relation to one another and displays three across rather than two. Think https://www.gumtree.com